# Custom jQuery slideshow not appending all data correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit rusty with jQuery, but I created a slideshow a couple years ago and I plugged it into a new website I'm building right now and I'm having issues.

The main issue I'm having is I got the background image in the code below to run through the slider correctly, but when I go to run the 'artist_name' data through the same slider code it doesn't loop correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Initial pull in of the projects feature
        $.getJSON("index.php/Home/pull_sponsored_videos", function(data) {
            // Sets global variables for returned json data
            window.$artist_name = data.artist_name;
            window.$song_title = data.song_title;
            window.$video_uri = data.video_uri;
            window.$cover_photo = data.cover_photo;

            // Turns returned json data into an array
            window.$cover_photo_array = $.map(window.$cover_photo, function(el) { return el; });
            window.$artist_name_array = $.map(window.$artist_name, function(el) { return el; });


            // Cover Photo Iteration Start
            var print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value_index = 0;
            var print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value_x;
            function print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value() {
                $('.sponsored_videos_slider').css('background-image','url('+window.$cover_photo_array[print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value_index]+')');

                // Test console
                console.log(window.$cover_photo_array[print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value_index])


                print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value_index= (print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value_index + 1) % window.$cover_photo_array.length;
            }
            print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value();
            print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value_x = setInterval(print_next_sponsored_video_picture_value, 5000);
            // Cover Photo Iteration End

            // Artist Name Iteration Start
            var print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value_index = 0;
            var print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value_x;
            function print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value() {
                $('.artist_name').text(window.$artist_name[print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value_index]);
                // Test console
                console.log(window.$artist_name[print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value_index]);
                print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value_index= (print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value_index + 1) % window.$artist_name.length;
            }
            print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value();
            print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value_x = setInterval(print_next_sponsored_video_artist_name_value(), 5000);
            // Artist Name Iteration End

        });

});
```

In the picture below the `'assets/images/sosagold_pornoflick_coverphoto.png'` and `'assets/images/kodakblack_skrilla.png'` outputs every time the slideshow changes image, but the output that reads....

```
Sosa Gold Ft. Ca$H
Kodak Black
```

... outputs one time to the console, and does not output to the slideshow accordingly, and the last value outputted `Kodak Black` is what's appended in the jQuery code.

[image]

So my question is am I missing anything? Because I've hit a standstill trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What are the lengths of the two arrays?

Comment: Both length arrays are returning 2